# Issue with PHP headers

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

So, I setup a webserver on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. I tried to access one of my PHP scripts through javascript, but it keeps giving me this error.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I already put this header in my PHP code.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

What do I do to get this to work?

Comment: are you sure your `header()` function is on top (before any output)? where do you put it? You do understand that it should be in requested script not requesting one, right?

Comment: Yes, it's literally on the 2nd line of my php code right under <?php

Comment: Or you could put it into .htaccess to whitelist your domain(s) you are calling your scripts from.

Comment: How would I do this with htaccess? @IncredibleHat

Comment: check in browser inspector if header is being sent

Comment: More reading that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: I know how it works, the thing is it just isn't working proporly